# Запуск после определенной даты

Tags: datetime, c++builder

```
Label1->Caption = Now();
```

Отправил данные настоящего времени в лэйбл...
Сделать выполнение функции после определенного числа...
Получается мне из Lable нужно вытащить дату и время, сделать условие, тогда можно было в Lable не добавлять...

А как я могу сравнить данные? Строчка такая 12.05.2011 15:13. Мне нужно тогда как-то взять каждое число отдельно и сделать под него условие...но как?

Answer (score 1):

Это нужно писать в обработчике события таймера:

```
TDateTime CurrentDateTime = Now();
if(CurrentDateTime >= AlarmDateTime)
{
    Form1->Show();
    Timer1->Enabled=false; // останавливаем таймер
}
```

`AlarmDateTime` - это заданные дата и время в формате `TDateTime`, когда форма должна быть показана, эту переменную нужно определить заранее. Можно сравнивать с датой-временем из `DatePicker`: `CurrentDateTime>=DateTimePicker1->DateTime`

[Пример работы с датой-временем](https://web.archive.org/web/20161124142557/http://cppbuilder.ru/articles/0164.php)